# Compare more than two TFS branches at the same time using TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, branch, compare

I want to compare four TFS branches at the same time using TFS 2010 and need to create report for the differences.
Any Idea ?

Thanks,
Minesh Bihola

Comment: Hmm, I've never even heard of tools that do 3- or 4-way diffs (with the exception of doing three-way merges). If there was a tool that did this at the file level you could get local copies of the different branches and then use that.

Comment: What kind of report do you expect?  Do you want to know the files that have changed across all branches?  Any branch?  Is one of these a common ancestor?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out-of-box with TFS/VS tools and I haven't seen other tools doing this either.